# Reading from a fifo C

Tags: c, fifo

I am trying to read from a fifo and i am not understanding it's behaviour.
This is the write side, write.c:

```
for(int i = 1;i<argc;i++){
    if(write(fifoFd,argv[i],strlen(argv[i])) <= 0)
      perror("Error writing");
  }
```

And this is the read side, read.c:

```
  char buf[1024];
  while(1){
    int b = read(fifoFd,buf,1024);
    if(b<=0) break;
  }
  printf("%s\n",buf);
```

First i start read.c `./read` then i execute `./write`
If i execute write like this `./write backup *.txt` sometimes i get what i expected, i.e, `backupexample1.txtexample2.txt`.
But sometimes i only get `example1.txtexample2.txt` and i am not understanding this, where is "backup"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
while(1){
  int b = read(fifoFd,buf,1024);
  if(b<=0) break;
}
printf("%s\n",buf);
```

You loop, each time through the loop you overwrite the buffer, and *then* you print the buffer. So, sometimes, you read "backup" followed by "example1.txtexample2.txt" (which overwrites "backup"), other times you read the whole lot at once in a single read.

If you change the loop to read into the unpopulated portion of the buffer, it will behave consistently:

```
int read = 0;
while(read != 1024){
  int b = read(fifoFd,buf+read,1024-read);
  if(b<=0) break;
  read += b;
}
printf("%s\n",buf);
```

Comment: But shouldn't the strings be written always in the same line?

Comment: @P_Ferreira  You don't write all the strings, only the last one your receive. The `printf` call is *after* the loop has completed.

Comment: But why sometimes backup is alone and sometimes the strings are in the same line?

Comment: @P_Ferreira because sometimes all the strings have been written to the pipe before you read from it, and sometimes it hasn't.